# How to show categories on cms home page slider in magento 1.9 ?

Tags: zend-framework2, magento-1.9

I am trying to show my categories in home page within a slider, that redirects to the relevant category page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ist you need to create  a custom Phtml file 
then use this code

```
<?php 
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0){
            echo $_category->getName();
            echo $_category->getId();      
            foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
                 echo $_subcategory->getName();
                 echo $_subcategory->getId();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Call it on your homepage then you can easily do HTML and slider what you want 
if you want more help you can ask me

Comment: Thanks arvind you save me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="YOUR_CATEGORY" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Step:- Need to put code in cms home page.and Put your category id in block.

Step2:- Here is the code of slider.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

  <ul class="bxslider">
     <li>Call block here </li>

</ul>
<script>
  jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
 });
</script>
```